# Ionic angular Bluetooth connectivity issue

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bluetooth

I am trying to listen for button clicks on a simple bluetooth remote.  I am able to connect to the bluetooth remote from my phone, but unable to start listening to the button clicks from the remote.  My main issue right now is that I don't know which services and characteristics the two buttons on the remote are.

The remote buttons do in fact work outside of my app, from the home screen they increase the volume and with the camera open they activate the shutter. Within my app I have tried various combinations of some 4 digit service and characteristic id's but am not getting any feedback inside my observable with the startNotifications call below.  I am also unsure if the service and characteristic ids are zeros or the letter O?  The deviceId seems to work with zero's as I am able to connect and get back device info.

I am using ionic, angular and this library below.  I'm using the ionViewDidEnter() hook for the code below.

https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central

```
const deviceId = '2A:07:98:10:40:05';
const serviceId = '1801';
const charId = '2902';

this.ble.connect(deviceId).subscribe(results => {
  // this.tempOutput = (JSON.stringify(results));
  this.tempOutput = 'connected to remote';

  this.ble.startNotification(deviceId, serviceId, charId).subscribe(buffer => {
    this.tempOutput = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buffer));
  }), (error: any) => {
    this.tempOutput = (JSON.stringify(error));
  }

});
```

Service/Characteristic output for remote device:

```
{
  "name": "AB Shutter3",
  "id": "2A:07:98:10:40:05",
  "services": [
    "1801",
    "1800",
    "180a",
    "1812",
    "180f"
  ],
  "characteristics": [
    {
      "service": "1801",
      "characteristic": "2a05",
      "properties": [
        "Indicate"
      ],
      "descriptors": [
        {
          "uuid": "2902"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a00",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a01",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1800",
      "characteristic": "2a04",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180a",
      "characteristic": "2a50",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1812",
      "characteristic": "2a4e",
      "properties": [
        "Read",
        "WriteWithoutResponse"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1812",
      "characteristic": "2a4d",
      "properties": [
        "Read",
        "Notify"
      ],
      "descriptors": [
        {
          "uuid": "2902"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "2908"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1812",
      "characteristic": "2a4d",
      "properties": [
        "Read",
        "Notify"
      ],
      "descriptors": [
        {
          "uuid": "2902"
        },
        {
          "uuid": "2908"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1812",
      "characteristic": "2a4b",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1812",
      "characteristic": "2a4a",
      "properties": [
        "Read"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "1812",
      "characteristic": "2a4c",
      "properties": [
        "WriteWithoutResponse"
      ]
    },
    {
      "service": "180f",
      "characteristic": "2a19",
      "properties": [
        "Read",
        "Notify"
      ],
      "descriptors": [
        {
          "uuid": "2902"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: It is always a bad idea to show a log output as picture instead of inserting it as text. However, you should concentrate on the GATT service 0x1812 which stands for a "Human Interface Device". More information on the numbers are available in the [16-bit UUID Numbers Document](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/) from the Bluetooth SIG

Comment: Thank you.  I updated the device output here with text rather than an image.